# when ubuntu disco will be supported?

Tags: ros-melodic, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

is there any date for a ROS release  supporting Ubuntu Disco (19.04 LTS) ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327739/when-ubuntu-disco-will-be-supported?/) by [emikfer](https://answers.ros.org/users/43975/emikfer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu Disco is not LTS. The next LTS will be Ubuntu 20.04.
The next version (and probably the last) of ROS1, called Noetic Ninjemys will target Ubuntu 20.04: https://discourse.ros.org/t/planning-future-ros-1-distribution-s/6538

More info: https://discourse.ros.org/t/proposed-changes-to-the-ros-releases/4736

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2019-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0